# CSS Half-Screen Browser Width

Tags: css

Everytime I drag my browser window so I have it automatically adjust to half monitor size, an empty block shows up on the side. I've tried changing the width to min-width: 100%, yet that doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/graphicDesign/index.php

CSS:

```
 div#bodyContent-container { 
    min-width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:1100px;
    background:#f3f3f3;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
 }
 div#bodyContent {
    width:960px;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px -7px #888, -6px 0px 10px -7px #888;
     -moz-box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px -7px #888, -6px 0px 10px -7px #888; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
    box-shadow: 6px 0px 10px -7px #888, -6px 0px 10px -7px #888;
    padding-top: 200px;
 }
footer {
    min-width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #161616; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%, #202020 92%, #131313 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#161616), color-stop(92%,#202020), color-stop(100%,#131313)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%,#202020 92%,#131313 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%,#202020 92%,#131313 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%,#202020 92%,#131313 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #161616 0%,#202020 92%,#131313 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#161616', endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi now **Define your** `body` `min-width:960px;` and **fixed** this problem

**as like this**

```
body{
min-width:960px;
}
```

**Result is**

[image]

Comment: define my body? As in the body tag itself?

Comment: @Andrew yes you can define in your stylesheet  in your body{min-width:960px;}